# HeatMap: how to cluster only the rows and keep order of the heatmap's column labels as same as in the df?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I wanna plot a heatmap and cluster only the rows (i.e. genes in this tydf1).
Also, wanna keep order of the heatmap's column labels as same as in the df (i.e. tydf1)?

**Sample data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gene = c("AA", "PQ", "XY", "UBQ"), X_T0_R1 = c(1.46559502, 0.220140568, 0.304127515, 1.098842127), X_T0_R2 = c(1.087642983, 0.237500819, 0.319844338, 1.256624804), X_T0_R3 = c(1.424945196, 0.21066267, 0.256496284, 1.467120048), X_T1_R1 = c(1.289943948, 0.207778662, 0.277942721, 1.238400358), X_T1_R2 = c(1.376535013, 0.488774258, 0.362562315, 0.671502431), X_T1_R3 = c(1.833390311, 0.182798731, 0.332856558, 1.448757569), X_T2_R1 = c(1.450753714, 0.247576125, 0.274415259, 1.035410946), X_T2_R2 = c(1.3094609, 0.390028842, 0.352460646, 0.946426593), X_T2_R3 = c(0.5953716, 1.007079177, 1.912258811, 0.827119776), X_T3_R1 = c(0.7906009, 0.730242116, 1.235644748, 0.832287694), X_T3_R2 = c(1.215333041, 1.012914813, 1.086362205, 1.00918082), X_T3_R3 = c(1.069312467, 0.780421013, 1.002313082, 1.031761442), Y_T0_R1 = c(0.053317766, 3.316414959, 3.617213894, 0.788193798), Y_T0_R2 = c(0.506623748, 3.599442788, 1.734075583, 1.179462912), Y_T0_R3 = c(0.713670106, 2.516735845, 1.236204882, 1.075393433), Y_T1_R1 = c(0.740998252, 1.444496448, 1.077023349, 0.869258744), Y_T1_R2 = c(0.648231834, 0.097957459, 0.791438659, 0.428805547), Y_T1_R3 = c(0.780499252, 0.187840968, 0.820430227, 0.51636582), Y_T2_R1 = c(0.35344654, 1.190274584, 0.401845911, 1.223534348), Y_T2_R2 = c(0.220223951, 1.367784148, 0.362815405, 1.102117612), Y_T2_R3 = c(0.432856978, 1.403057729, 0.10802472, 1.304233845), Y_T3_R1 = c(0.234963735, 1.232129062, 0.072433381, 1.203096462), Y_T3_R2 = c(0.353770497, 0.885122768, 0.011662112, 1.188149743), Y_T3_R3 = c(0.396091395, 1.333921747, 0.192594116, 1.838029829), Z_T0_R1 = c(0.398000559, 1.286528398, 0.129147097, 1.452769794), Z_T0_R2 = c(0.384759325, 1.122251177, 0.119475721, 1.385513609), Z_T0_R3 = c(1.582230097, 0.697419716, 2.406671502, 0.477415567), Z_T1_R1 = c(1.136843842, 0.804552001, 2.13213228, 0.989075996), Z_T1_R2 = c(1.275683837, 1.227821594, 0.31900326, 0.835941568), Z_T1_R3 = c(0.963349308, 0.968589683, 1.706670339, 0.807060135), Z_T2_R1 = c(3.765036263, 0.477443352, 1.712841882, 0.469173869), Z_T2_R2 = c(1.901023385, 0.832736132, 2.223429427, 0.593558769), Z_T2_R3 = c(1.407713024, 0.911920317, 2.011259223, 0.692553388), Z_T3_R1 = c(0.988333629, 1.095130142, 1.648598854, 0.629915612), Z_T3_R2 = c(0.618606729, 0.497458337, 0.549147265, 1.249492088), Z_T3_R3 = c(0.429823986, 0.471389536, 0.977124788, 1.136635484)), row.names = c(NA, -4L ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

**Scripts used**

```
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) 
library(tidyr) 
gdf1 <- gather(df1, "group", "Expression", -Gene) 
gdf1$tgroup <- apply(str_split_fixed(gdf1$group, "_", 3)[, c(1, 2)], 
                     1, paste, collapse ="_")

library(dplyr) 
tydf1 <- gdf1 %>% 
  group_by(Gene, tgroup) %>% 
  summarize(expression_mean = mean(Expression)) %>% 
  spread(., tgroup, expression_mean)
```

**#1 heatmap script is being used**

```
library(tidyverse)
tydf1 <- tydf1 %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var=colnames(tydf1)[1]) 

library(gplots) 
library(vegan) 
randup.m <- as.matrix(tydf1) 
scaleRYG <- colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","darkgreen"), 
                             space = "rgb")(30) 
data.dist <- vegdist(randup.m, method = "euclidean") 
row.clus <- hclust(data.dist, "aver") 
heatmap.2(randup.m, Rowv = as.dendrogram(row.clus), 
          dendrogram = "row", col = scaleRYG, margins = c(7,10), 
          density.info = "none", trace = "none", lhei = c(2,6), 
          colsep = 1:3, sepcolor = "black", sepwidth = c(0.001,0.0001), 
          xlab = "Identifier", ylab = "Rows")
```

**#2 heatmap script is being used**

```
df2 <- as.matrix(tydf1[, -1]) 
heatmap(df2)
```

Also, I want to add a color key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still unclear to me, what the desired output is. There are some notes:

- You don't need to use `vegdist()` to calculate distance matrix for your `hclust()` call. Because if you check `all(vegdist(randup.m, method = "euclidian") == dist(randup.m))` it returns `TRUE`;
- Specifying `Colv = F` in your `heatmap.2()` call will prevent reordering of the columns (default is `TRUE`);
- Maybe it is better to scale your data by row (see the uncommented row);
- Your call of `heatmap.2()` returns the heatmap with color key.

So summing it up - in your first script you just miss the `Colv = F` argument, and after a little adjustment it looks like this:

```
heatmap.2(randup.m, 
          Rowv = as.dendrogram(row.clus),
          Colv = F,
          dendrogram = "row", 
          #scale = "row", 
          col = scaleRYG,
          density.info = "none",
          trace = "none",
          srtCol = -45,
          adjCol = c(.1, .5),
          xlab = "Identifier",
          ylab = "Rows"
          )
```

[image: heatmap.2]

However I am still not sure - is it what you need?

Comment: I have several experimental conditions. therefore I wanna keep columns without clustering to compare with other heatmaps.  #Thank you very much utubun. I greatly appreciate your time and kind help.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem with column clustering. Just thinking about the distance... Your distance matrix is a distance between levels of the gen's expression. But maybe the level of expression itself is not a good distance measure? Because in situation when both genes are upregulated but one is highly expressed and another is not you assign them to different clusters, which you shouldn't. If you try `dist2 <- as.dist(1 - as.matrix(cor(t(randup.m), method = "pearson"), dimnames = dimnames(randup.m)))` you'll see difference. But don't trust me, do some research by yourself.

Comment: May I ask , Why my color key is not appearing. I've tried with key=TRUE, keysize=1.0, key.xlab = "Ln(Peak Area / T0)", key.ylab="", key.title="" too

Comment: Probably, it is because in your call of `heatmap.2()` you use `lhei = c(2,6)` try to change it to `lhei = c(3, 6)`. If you see an error message in console (`Error in .External.graphics...`) try `dev.off()` and call the `heatmap.2(...)` again.

Comment: I wanna favor from you, in my heatmap cloumns are rearranging according to alphabetical order (here group "X", "Y", and "Z", but my working df names are in "WT", "A1", "A2", in the heatmap this rearrange to "A1", "A2", "WT" this order ). How can I stop this?